# How do I know that it has been abort from client in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

It has render the results accepted a request by ajax from the client in Ruby on Rails, with the heavy processing in the action on the server side. 
However, if the client had been abort during until the start of action, I want to avoid the processing of heavy action, but possible? 
and the action is not may be performed, but I want to avoid the heavy processing to check the connection status of the client at the beginning of the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is no specific way to stop an action based on user response. The rule is: Once the action is executed it runs.

You can use `before_filter` to check a client connection. And return `:response => Ok` to stop execution. Please let me know if you want me to elaborate on this

Also you can try to put all `heavy` actions under a delayed_job execution. See: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job